# htaccess rewrite for clean image url

Tags: image, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a re-write for an [identicon](http://www.permissiondenied.net/identicon/?so) generator where something like

```
images/1-2.png
```

Would be interpretted on the server as

```
images/index.php?one=1&two=2
```

But it would still show `site.com/images/1-2.png` in the address bar.

Assumed there's only one dash (-) in the file name

Doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it, put this in your .htaccess file in the root of your application.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^images/(\d)-(\d)\.png          images/index.php?one=$1&two=$2 [NC,L]
```